# Is there a name for "slapping" a hammond organ?

Tags: terminology, organ

Just wondering if there was a technical name for the keyboard "slap" technique found here at around 4:00ish:

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.  Organs aren't touch sensitive, so there's no effect to the sound, it's just this guy's way of getting extremely short staccato notes.

Comment: Thinking about this again, I still agree with you although I think there is an important distinction -- his "short, staccato" notes aren't necessarily intentionally selected notes, they're somewhat random hits on the keyboard without regard for the notes, which creates a more percussive, rhythmic sound to me. An analogous concept to this I think would be guitar damping/scratching. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping_%28music%29 and a sample: http://youtu.be/Prh2Jkt1nLE